# Insert tbody content into the database

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have the following Java script function:

```
var tabBody, row, cell;

function updateTable()
{
    tabBody = document.getElementById("editable");
    row = document.createElement("tr");

    cellID = document.createElement("td");
    cellname = document.createElement("td");

    cellID.innerHTML = document.forms['myForm1'].elements[1].value;
    cellname.innerHTML = document.forms['myForm1'].elements[0].value;

    row.appendChild(cellID);
    row.appendChild(cellname);

    if (tabBody.childNodes.length == 10)
    {
        tabBody.removeChild(tabBody.childNodes[0])
    }

    document.getElementById("mytb").style.display = "block";

    tabBody.appendChild(row);
}
```

and the tbody appears when adding data to input text like: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v1eS.png)

How can I get this data to be inserted in the database?

Comment: Which data and what database?

Comment: I want to insert the names and the IDs which are in the tbody into a table in a database

Comment: Do you already have a database on the server?

Comment: sure, I have also a table to insert these data in.

Comment: Mention the database you used?

Comment: oracle database,, but I don't understand why the database type is important??
I just want a way to pass data from java script function (client side) to a java class which contains a code for inserting these data into the database

Comment: There are many different ways of getting data back to the server for storage into the database.  Rather than try and figure out which way most suits your current architecture you should give more information that is relevant to your question such as "using jquery, ajax, mysql, servlets, jsp."

Comment: I just want the way of getting data NOT how to insert it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must loop each element of you tbody and get each value.
for example using jquery:

```
// this will get all lines of your table
$("#editable tr").each(function(index,element){
  // here element is the current line (<tr>) of the loop

   // here we get all <td> of <tr>
  $(element).children().each(function(tdIndex,tdElement){
   // here we get the value of current <td>
   var value = $(tdElement).html();// value of td content
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the data back to the server could use an ajax call.

Such as:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "receivedata.jsp?p1=" + document.forms['myForm1'].elements[1].value + "&p2=" + document.forms['myForm1'].elements[0].value )
  .done(function() {
       alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
      alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
     alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Above extract taken from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If using JSP on the server side you get the p1 and p2 parameters.